# Destroying a user can leave a bounty open on a deleted question

Tags: bug, status-declined, bounties, deleted-accounts

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378104/stopping-threads-nicely-within-a-class-wrapper-thinger) is a bit of an odd case.

The user placed a bounty on it, then engaged in a rollback war culminating with a lock. He then requested his account to be deleted. It was. The question, which was at -1 at the time, was automatically deleted along with the account. This should not happen since bounty questions ordinarily can be neither closed nor deleted.

Now the bounty languishes in a limbo state, its clock ticking away in futility, hoping against desperate hope that someone somewhere will rescue it. But no one hears its cries.

[image: Bounty offered by Community ♦]

Cheer? No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: Now we get to find out if bounties *really* work...

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to look again in five days.

Comment: Now it says "This question had a bounty worth +100 reputation from Community♦ that ended 18 hours ago; grace period ends in 5 hours" LOL!!

Comment: The period has ended, and the bounty is still in a frozen state. The exact message is as follows: *"This question had a bounty worth +100 reputation from Community♦ that ended yesterday; grace period has ended"*

Comment: It seems to have worked itself out: the last two [revision items](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8378104/revisions) are 'bounty ended with no winning answer' and 'bounty notice removed'. No answer was awarded bounty rep.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing bad happens from this "bug", the bounty simply times out with no action.

It should also be exceedingly rare to have a user deleted with a bounty in flight.

Thus, I don't think any action is warranted here.

Comment: When the account was deleted, who deleted the account could have got a warning about the user having an open bounty. The question is now: "Could who deleted the account have taken a different decision, knowing the user had an open bounty?" If the answer is no, then it is useless to give a warning.