# Question deleted out of sheer frustration?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I wonder why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378104/stopping-threads-nicely-within-a-class-wrapper-thinger) (10K+ only) got deleted; it looks like a good question with some answers that got upvotes and even with a bounty.

From this comment made by the OP:

> if you cant understand the question, then you are probably not good enough to answer it. you cant really get any simpler explanation. ill withdraw it. thanks for the help

I assume he got frustrated, tried to delete the question and when he saw he can't (as it had answers) he asked to delete his account thus nuking the question, or other option started to troll/spam until moderator nuked his account.

From what I know about this place, good contents should be reserved—once something was submitted, it belongs to the community (unless if it contains sensitive information of course)—right?

So, is there any reason not to restore that question?

Edit: just now saw [the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8378104/revisions) which clearly [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8378104/12) why he got banned. :-S

Comment: Well at least you've shown me something that makes me laugh on this cold December morning :)

Comment: Without being 10k I'll make the guess that the question was removed to prevent any more discussions and/or hassles.

Comment: @AakashM: Okay, now I want sceenshots!

Comment: Question talked about here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115503/destroying-a-user-can-leave-a-bounty-open-on-a-deleted-question

Comment: Ahahaha! `IT SAYS DO NOT F---ING EDIT POMPOUS PROGRAMMER `

Comment: @Bobby the question was already Locked, meaning no further edits can be done. No need to kill it to hide the shame. no need for screenshots, it was just edit war between the question author and other members.

Comment: @Mat yep but from different angle of why Bounty should stay active in such situation (instead of simply auto expiring)

Comment: Good content should be preserved, sure.  But once he did that to his edit history, all bets were off.  At that point he makes the leap from "asking" to "trolling" and should expect to be removed with extreme prejudice.  He may have deleted the question himself, but it's noisy enough that I don't see restoring it.

Comment: @David I agree he should have been banned, but why not leave the question? The noise is well hidden in the revision history, nobody should care - if noise should cause questions to be deleted, what's the point of roll back?

Comment: I've never edited a programmer at all, whether pompous or not. (Their programs… well, that's another matter.)