# Bounty grace period claims to be expired while it's in its last hour

Tags: bug, bounties, timestamps, expired-bounty

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378104/stopping-threads-nicely-within-a-class-wrapper-thinger) (10k, sorry), which is being discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115503/destroying-a-user-can-leave-a-bounty-open-on-a-deleted-question), has a bounty that ended "`at 2011-12-14 17:06:44Z`", but as of now (`2011-12-15 16:30:00Z`, near enough) "the grace period has ended".

Isn't the grace period 24 hours, so there's another 36 minutes to go before it's ended?

Comment: Normally I'd support a question like this, but in this particular case I think it might be better to note the behavior as an update to mmyers's post.

Comment: @Popular Hmm, I thought it might be a general problem to all bounties and not specific to that situation. Is there a sandbox-y way to test bounties? If not I'm sure I can find some suitable answer to test on...