# 'Community' user owning a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Destroying a user can leave a bounty open on a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115503/destroying-a-user-can-leave-a-bounty-open-on-a-deleted-question)
>   [How Does the Community User Set Bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139533/how-does-the-community-user-set-bounties)

I apologize if this has been answered before, but I looked around and could not find anything on it. I happened to come across [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)'s profile today, and it turns out that it has an [active bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927067/domain-name-classification-api), with 4 days remaining. How is this possible? The only thing I can think of is from Community's profile description:

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention.

Does this include adding bounties? If so, what is the criteria for getting a question awarded a community bounty? The only other thing I can think of is that these bounties are from users who had their accounts deleted; is this the case?

For future reference, here is a screenshot of the active bounty:

[image: Active bounty for 50 reputation]

Comment: @kiamlaluno doesn't help, as the question has no revision history.

Comment: Well, I'll see your downvotes and raise you a "Close as duplicate" vote :) I went to look for documentation, and it does seem like this has been discussed before.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill no problem. If this is a duplicate, then it deserves to be closed. I just couldn't find it, any time I searched for `community` and `bounty`, I just got results on community rewarding bounties.

Comment: There are quite a few  relevant  discussions if you search for "deleted user community bounty"

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Every question has a revision, even if the link doesn't appear. Try with `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9927067/revisions`. Also, the other question contains an answer given from a developer; there is nothing more official than that.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill at any rate, I can't delete the question, as there are answers, but I will vote to close it my self. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive but I believe that indicates that the user who offered the bounty has been deleted. The question-asker account still exists, so it must have been a third-party bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the original user that offered the bounty has been deleted.

See [How Does the Community User Set Bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139533/how-does-the-community-user-set-bounties)
And [Destroying a user can leave a bounty open on a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115503/destroying-a-user-can-leave-a-bounty-open-on-a-deleted-question)